# PDF is blank when downloading

Tags: node.js, express, file, file-upload, download

I am getting a blank pdf when downloading

```
exports.getInvoice = (req, res, next) => {
    const orderId = req.params.orderId;
    const invoiceName = 'invoice-' + orderId + '.pdf';
    const invoicePath = path.join('data', 'invoices', invoiceName);
    fs.readFile(invoicePath, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        res.setHeader(
            'Content-Disposition',
            'attachment; filename="' + invoiceName + '"'
            );
        res.send(data);
    }); 
};
```

I tried to download the invoice, which is manually created and just tried to download from here with contents in it, but simply gets a blank invoice.

Comment: I was learning based on a tutorial and there 2 headers are set

Comment: Looks like reading a file from local path getting orderId from request object.
You need to add/check request object , what path you are looking at, whether file exists there. Such details are missing to answer you question.

Comment: I am able to generate the invoice dynamically with the below, but the problem is when I try to download the manually generated invoices like this .. 
is it because any plugin or something is missing, like the tutor is using mac and i am using windows